# how to setup quartz.net for many customer databases

Tags: quartz.net

I'm sure someone has come across this scenario before. We're rolling out a product where each customer has a separate copy of a database and each customer requires quartz.net jobs.

Are there any recommendations on how to configure quartz to run against each copy of the database?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run separate instances for each database. Each scheduler runs against a single database instance.